# how to make Sony A7Rii take bracketed photos in linear order

Tags: bracketing, sony-alpha

How do I make a Sony A7Rii take bracketed photos in linear order, rather than in sub-groups?

The hard copy manual doesn't help, and I haven't found out anything on Google either.

Comment: I don't own a Sony, but what about this? https://photofocus.com/2016/07/19/setting-up-bracketing-on-sony-cameras/

Comment: But you did find the PDF Manual? https://www.sony.co.uk/electronics/support/res/manuals/4576/45769834M.pdf

Comment: You found it @MikeDixon, thanks. Add an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 2):

[**Drive Mode** and **Bracketing**](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1520/v1/en/cover/level3_20.html) are described in the [manual](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1520/v1/h_zz/index.html). There is a setting to [change bracket order](http://helpguide.sony.net/ilc/1520/v1/en/contents/TP0001097462.html) that may do what you want.